# An internal error occurred during: "Check Android SDK"

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am going to create a Android application project in eclipse,[image]so I am getting this exception. Give me any suggestions to get rid of this. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled ADT plugin from eclipse and reinstalled it again. It solved my issue.That's it.

May it helps to some one.Thanks.